# Как загрузить все файлы из каталога?

Tags: apache, ftp, php

Есть такая страница: [Index of /dist/httpd/](http://apache.rinet.ru/dist/httpd/). Как нужно скачаивать весь каталог? Составить каталог файлов и скачать их по ссылке? Есть ли другой способ?

Comment: С помощью программы Teleport Pro попробуй.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если правильно понял вопрос..нужно скачать из директории http://site.com/dist/httpd/ все файлы..верно?

тогда нужна прога winhttrack 
http://www.httrack.com/
указываешь язык..русский..указываешь откуда ей начинать качать и куда.. и вуаля